# Angular.js - Change a selected option from a button with data binding as a function parameter

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-click

I want to change the selected option with a button.  If I do not use data binding in the parameters the code works as expected:

```
ng-click="changeOptions('cat');"
```

If I use data binding for the parameters it no longer works.  Is this not allowed?

```
ng-click="changeOptions('{{animals.type}}');"
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="quickApp" ng-controller="quickController">
    <select ng-model="animalList" ng-options="animals.type as animals.type for animals in animals"></select>
    <button ng-repeat="animals in animals" ng-click="changeOptions('{{animals.type}}');">{{animals.type}}</button>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
angular
    .module('quickApp', [])

    .controller('quickController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.changeOptions = function(id){
               $scope.animalList = id;
           };

        $scope.animals = [
                {'type':'cat'},
                {'type':'dog'},
                {'type':'bear'}
        ];
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need those curly braces.

```
ng-click="changeOptions(animals.type);"
```

Should work

By the way, Why dont you change `animals in animals` to `animal in animals`? Two `animals` seems ambiguous. In that case you have to use:

```
<button ng-repeat="animal in animals" ng-click="changeOptions('{{animal.type}}');">{{animal.type}}</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestions helped get me to a point where it is now working correctly. 

It was initially confusing as looking at the DOM, both using a 'string' and {{data binding}} as a parameter rendered exactly the same, yet yielded different results.